# RunMojo compatibility problem with camel plugin

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, apache-camel, intellij-plugin, mojo

I have installed [Camel plugin for IntelliJ](https://github.com/camel-tooling/camel-idea-plugin).

To start debugging, we must create an ad-hoc application

[image]

The problem is that it gives me that error running it, when building the war file

> org/apache/camel/maven/RunMojo has been compiled by a more recent
> version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of
> the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I can't just find where the problem is. I have checked all the java versions defined everywhere and seems fine...

[image]

[image]

[image]

in the POM

[image]

[image]

so what can be the problem? Mojo version is

[image]

Comment: The plugin has been compiled with JDK 11 and requires the minimum JDK version 11 to work with... (class file version 55.0)... but you have a project which is using JDK8 which will simply not work.".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The plugin has been compiled with JDK 11 and requires the minimum JDK version 11 to work with.

Comment: To add on top of the great answer of Lore. I woudl like to mention also more context. Java 11 is required since Camel 3.15 https://camel.apache.org/releases/release-3.15.0/#whats_new
Debug features in Camel IDEA requires Java 3.16+ (as far as I know, maybe 3.17+)